# Routing traffic from abc.com to xyz.com/abc

Tags: networking

What is the most reliable way to route traffic from `abc.com` to `xyz.com/abc`? How does the server at `xyz.com` know for sure how to route the traffic to the `/abc` path?

I understand that it might be a lot easier to route traffic from `abc.com` to `abc.xyz.com`, but looking to do something potentially more dynamic here.

Comment: What technology are you asking about? nginx? apache2?

Comment: I guess I meant what information does it use to do it? what is the most reliable piece of information or technique regardless of aoache vs nginx?

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for a reverse proxy. Lots of loadbalancer type software has this functionality. Nginx and apache are very popular ones.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it's the best option, but I would do as you described, first routing `abc.com` to `abc.xyz.com` via DNS records, and then letting the webserver, through a virtual host (at least that's how Apache calls it), take care of the redirection from `abc.xyz.com` to `xyz.com/abc`.